# How to restrict API's to run only in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, mean-stack

I am using node js and i put polices to restrict the api's accurance otherthan in browser.For that i put the following condition

```
app.route('/students').all(policy.checkHeader).get(courses.list)

exports.checkHeader =  function(req, res, next) {
    var headers = req.headers;
       if ( headers['upgrade-insecure-requests'] || headers['postman-token']) {
        res.status(401).json('Page not found');
    } else {
        return next();
    }

}
```

I am not sure whether my process is correct.I am searching for the common parameter(header-parameter) that exists only for the browser.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible.

You can't control what types of clients make HTTP requests to your HTTP server.

You can't reliably identify what type of client has made a request you receive.

An upgrade-insecure-requests header can be sent (or not sent) with any value by any custom client. Ditto postman-token. Ditto user-agent. Ditto everything else.

The only way to restrict it would be to require some kind of secret in the request. If you want regular web browsers to access it, then the secret will leak through the browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to really block the requests without Authentication / Authorization. However, you can use the HTTP Header's User-Agent field

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html