# My backend Flask Rest API end-points are open to public. How to secure?

Tags: python, security, flask, rest

I've created a REST API for only get-requests and provides data to the front end.

My friend is currently building the front-end.

Right now, anyone can access the api end points by looking at the network tab, however I want to limit the access to the front-end my friend is building. The site will not require a login system (initially), but maybe have in the future.

I've read about tokens and keys, but it seems this information will show up in the browser, which I assume will be easy to reverse engineer.

So how should I protect the API in a way to limit access from scrapers or anyone with ill intent?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict API's to run only in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588012/how-to-restrict-apis-to-run-only-in-the-browser)

Comment: There no single step solution when it comes to security. You can also consider using Flask-Limiter https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Securing your API may be easiest migrating from Flask to a framework that has more support for security from the community.

Django has a great package, django-oauth2-provider, that allows you to secure your application similiar to how large companies secure theirs. It will take time to learn the underlying architecture as proposed per RFC 6749, though in understanding how this problem of reverse engineering tokens within the browser is prevented here may be of interest to you.

This protocol allows for secure authorization and authentication over the web, despite the client-side data transmission that is observable from the browser, by requiring a handshake between the user and your server.

A reasonable starting place to restrict your existing app may be to add a proxy in front of it requiring a `Basic Authorization Token` in the header. This could be done with a reverse proxy like Apache2 or Nginx. Here is the official Apache2 spec on this setup: http://doc.norang.ca/apache-basic-auth.html.

There may be even packages that already exist to restrict access to your Flask app, you could implement your own code to secure your app, yet this is a common problem and has been solved before, so why not take advantage of what is available?